# Wrong date in certificate

Tags: graduation

My university made a mistake on my graduation parchment, which is the graduation date (they wrote the whole date in words so I guess that's how they made mistake, even I myself take years to realize that). But luckily, it's correct in the transcript.

Should I inform them to correct it now? It's been years since then. Problem is I'm in the middle of an application and the deadline is coming soon. Should I just submit as usual and respond if inquiry arises?

Comment: How wrong is the date?  Many years wrong, one year wrong, a few days wrong?

Comment: Following on from my answer at http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/38502/929 I would totally forge a new diploma with the correct date.

Comment: Country? Because some of the answers seem very weird to me, therefore, it might depend on the country....

Answer (score 5):

Very few places look at certificates when looking at applications.  Certified transcripts are considered the authoritative source.  If it's correct in the transcript, then that will be fine for the application.  If they wish to validate the transcripts, they will contact the institution directly whose records will match the transcript, not the certificate (almost certainly).

As for correcting the certificate, some institutions allow you to contact their registrar's office and request a re-printing of the certificate.  If it has been many years, the biggest problem is often that the Provost/Chancellor, etc. of the institution may have changed, so the signatures may not be the same as when you were issued your degree.  The specifics depend on institution.  There's no harm in calling or emailing them and inquiring.